# PAM failing to authenticate sudo, after successfully contacting ssh-agent

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, sudo, authentication, pam

Setting up PAM `sudo` authentication, using `ssh-agent`, on 14.04.1-Ubuntu server LTS.

I'm still unable to successfully authenticate sudo, via the ssh-agent, using PAM.

Here are my relevant `/var/log/auth.log` entries...

```
Jun 17 11:31:16 host sudo[21318]: pam_ssh_agent_auth: Beginning pam_ssh_agent_auth for user userName
Jun 17 11:31:16 host sudo[21318]: pam_ssh_agent_auth: Attempting authentication: `userName' as `userName' using /etc/security/authorized_keys
Jun 17 11:31:16 host sudo[21318]: pam_ssh_agent_auth: Contacted ssh-agent of user userName (1000)
Jun 17 11:31:16 host sudo[21318]: pam_ssh_agent_auth: Failed Authentication: `userName' as `userName' using /etc/security/authorized_keys
```

As you can see, it successfully contacts the `ssh-agent`, but then authentication fails.  PAM falls back to the next authentication method(s), and asks for the sudo/userName password, then I'm able to proceed.  I'm trying to configure it, so that you don't need a `sudo` password, as long as you connect via `ssh` with an authorized key.

Here are the relevant files and their contents:

**/etc/pam.d/sudo**

```
#%PAM-1.0

auth       sufficient pam_ssh_agent_auth.so file=/etc/security/authorized_keys debug
auth       required   pam_env.so readenv=1 user_readenv=0
auth       required   pam_env.so readenv=1 envfile=/etc/default/locale user_readenv=0

@include common-auth
@include common-account
@include common-session-noninteractive
```

**/etc/security/authorized_keys** file information: This file contains 4 `ssh-rsa` public keys.

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1597 Jun 16 16:07 /etc/security/authorized_keys
```

**/etc/sudoers**

```
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#

Defaults        env_keep += SSH_AUTH_SOCK

Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        mail_badpass
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

And, for sanity's sake, you can see the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` is indeed being "passed up the `sudo` chain" correctly...

`printenv | grep SSH`

`SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-m9Ume3GOIP/agent.15964`

`sudo printenv | grep SSH`

`SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-m9Ume3GOIP/agent.15964`

I ssh into the server via

```
ssh -A host@ip_address
```

I'll include any other information that may be helpful, just ask :)

I've been at this for over a day, and I've found dozens of "howtos" to setup PAM `sudo` authentication using `ssh` keys, and they're all similar... but I can't find anything that might shine light on why the PAM authentication fails, after successfully contacting/communicating with the `ssh-agent`.

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

`ssh-add` on the client side, was the trick.  I'm not an "ssh power user", but this gives me what I need to figure out the root cause.  Thanks!

Comment: `ssh-add -L` will return something on your local computer and on the remote host?

Comment: That did the trick =D

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but I suspect you don't have the agent running or you don't have the keys added. Is there anything unclear yet?

Comment: I simply ran ssh-add on the client, and that was able to load the private key into the agent, which allowed PAM to successfully authenticate on the server.  I may still be missing something, but I'm currently researching "what that means."  I'm not an "ssh power user", so I may still be missing something, but this gives me a jumping off point to further my research at least :)

Comment: `ssh-add -L` on either system, prior to doing that, simply returned `The agent has no identities.`

Comment: I believe it is all you missed in your configuration. I will write you some answer :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Configuration is OK, but you need to have some identities in your `ssh-agent` to be able to authorize the `sudo` operation. You can verify that your agent has some identities using

```
ssh-add -L
```

It should print the public keys in your agent and at least one of them should match the public key on server in `/etc/security/authorized_keys`.

If the agent does not have any identities, you need to add them on your computer, again using

```
ssh-add [path/to/key]
```

and insert your passphrase, if prompted.

Answer (score 1):

I have added this `.bashrc` on my user that need `ssh-agent` running, I use it for a special ansible user.
I noticed many `ssh-agent` process and I tried to keep it clean on every login to clean it.

Just to be clear the `ssh-agent` must run on the **server** where the connection is made from.

`$HOME/.bashrc`

```
CSSH=$(ssh-add -L 2>/dev/null |grep -c ssh-rsa)
if [ $CSSH -eq 0 ]; then
 pkill ssh-agent
 eval `ssh-agent -s`
 ssh-add
else
 echo "SSH agent already running"
fi
```